# What's the difference between 'Enter orbit' and 'Move here' in Stellaris?

Tags: stellaris

There was a debate in our C&C center about the difference between 'Enter orbit' and 'Move here'.

I personally told them that I'm sure there is no difference at all :-).

So, is there any difference? 
Why is it that out fleet commanders use two different orders to issue the same command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For most celestial bodies, there's no difference. You tell it to go into orbit, and it just stops there. The icon on the sidebar will be red, showing it as idle.

For some bodies, specifically planets that you own, it will put the ship in orbit, which is different than simply being nearby. The icon on the sidebar will be green, indicating orbit.

When in orbit around one of your planets, fleets:

- have reduced upkeep costs
- can be repaired
- can be upgraded
- can be affected by spaceport modules, such as the Crew Quarters which reduces upkeep costs
- will merge with any new ships constructed at the planet

Fleets also need to be in orbit in order to bombard a planet, and transport fleets must be in orbit in order to land their troops.

Comment: O.K, seems there is a big difference, I'll go tell the guys - 10x :-)

Answer (score 0):

Move into orbit will keep the ship location moving with the planet as they move through orbit.

Meanwhile move here is more useful if you want to stay in this location in respect to the solar system overall region.

For example, if you want a construction ship to stay in this location to build a FTL trap. It just happens to have a planet in that location moving through. You might want to use stay here to not waste time between moving from planet's future location and this location.

The same can be said of starbase.

Comment: Are you saying the planets actually move through their orbits about their stars? I don't think that that's the case. Maybe I'm just blind.

Comment: They move very very slowly. But if you print a screenshot at game start. Then go for a few years then take another screenshot. You will notice they move slowly. But it don't move very realistic (much slower than a year would take in real life).

Comment: Interesting. I will try and watch for that. Do you think that ships will stick with a planet after being told to go into orbit, even if they're shown as 'idle' on the sidebar, rather than 'in orbit'?

Comment: There is actually two different icons for idling vs "in orbit".